# I'm new to the software and I'm getting this error while trying to install react native on macos, can you help me?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, macos, native

[image]

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-manifest, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/emrebaser/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.facebook.react/react-native/0.71.0-rc.0/7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543/react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar.
> > Java heap space

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install ReactJS on MacOS, you must first have NodeJS and NPM installed.

The only way you can install NodeJS is through their official website: https://nodejs.org/.
Installing NodeJS will also automatically download NPM on your machine.
The you can check if the installation was successful:

‘’’
node —version
npm —version
‘’’

If its successful you should get the version.

Than to install react you run this command:

‘’’
npm install --save react react-dom
‘’’

And to create the project:

‘’’
npm create-react-app nameOfProject
,,,